# AttributeError at /website/tbt.html 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to generate a pdf from data taken by the user. in this case it contains a few fields as shown in models. It gives me an error after I hit the submit button
my models.py

```
    tbt_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name="Date of Creation", default=timezone.now
    )
    selected_site = models.ForeignKey(
        sites_data, verbose_name="Choose a site", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    selected_block = models.ForeignKey(
        blocks_list, verbose_name="Choose a block", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
    tbt_report_img1 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="formImages/TBT/", verbose_name="Upload Image 1"
    )
    tbt_report_img2 = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="formImages/TBT/", verbose_name="Upload Image 2"
    )
    rt_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/', verbose_name='PDF File', null=True)
```

my views.py

```
    tbt_form_view = tbt_report_form()
    context = {
        "loggedInUser": request.user,
        "tbt_form":tbt_form_view,
    }
    return context


#@login_required(login_url="user_login")
def generate_tbt_report(request, t_form, selected_form, filename):
    selected_site = t_form.selected_site
    selected_block = t_form.selected_block
    selected_site_data = sites_data.objects.filter(name=selected_site)[0]
    tbt_date = t_form.tbt_date
    print(tbt_date)
    params = {
        "selected_site": selected_site_data,
        "tbt_date": tbt_date,
        "selected_block": selected_block,
        "t": t_form,
        "data": selected_form,
        "loggedInUser": request.user,
    }
    template_path = "website/tbt_report_pdf.html"
    temp_pdf = render_to_pdf(request, template_path, params, filename)
    return temp_pdf

@login_required(login_url="user_login")
def tbt_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        t_form=tbt_report_form(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        t_form.full_clean()
        print("in post")
        if t_form.is_valid():
            print("Valid")
            t_form = t_form.save()
            filename='TBT' + ' ' + str(t_form.tbt_date) + ' ' + str(t_form.selected_block) + '.pdf'
            pdf = generate_tbt_report(request, t_form, filename)
            cv_get = tbt_report.objects.get(id = t_form.id)  
            cv_get.rt_pdf.save(filename, File(BytesIO(pdf.content)))
            print("Saved")
            return pdf
        else:
            print("1")
            print(t_form)
            messages.error(
                request=request, message="Please check all the fields entered!!!"
            )
            return render(request, "website/tbt.html", context=tbtform(request))

    else:
        return render(request, "website/tbt.html", context=tbtform(request))
```

my tbt.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <style>
        /* .tab {
            display: none;
        } */

        label {
            font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding-top: 18px;
            border-bottom: 5px inset #008000;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .form-control-file {
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 12px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title>VoltAmp - Solar Panacea</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" style="padding: 5% 12% 10% 12%;">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="{% static 'website/img/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <form method="POST" role="form" id='tbt_form' enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            data-blocks-url="{% url 'ajax_load_blocks' %}" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.tags == "error" %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {% else %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {% endif %}
                    <a class="close" href="" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

                <div class="container" style="background-color: #FFFF00;padding: 4% ;">
                    <h1 class="text-center"
                        style="font-weight: bold;font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif">
                        TBT
                    </h1>
                </div>

                <div class="tab">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ tbt_form|crispy }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="overflow:auto;">

                    <div class="col-sm-12 d-grid gap-2 pt-3">
                        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 d-grid gap-2 pt-3">
                        <a href="{% url 'user_logout' %}"><input type="button" id="logoutBtn"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Logout"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            
</body>

</html>
```

This gives me an error that says:

AttributeError at /website/tbt.html
'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Comment: I don't see where you are doing a `user.get()` or anything similar, like using a ForignKey. The error is saying you've got a *literal* **User** Object and you are trying to use the get method. `User.objects.get() == valid` but `User.objects.get(pk=1).get() == invalid` + `request.user.get() == invalid` - hopefully this helps you narrow it down, look for get calls.

Comment: Traceback
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
   return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "F:\voltampmaintenance\sitedata\views.py", line 211, in tbt_form
    t_form.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 372, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 384, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))

Comment: File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 263, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya\.virtualenvs\voltampmaintenance-jsz0XWiV\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 247, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
Exception Type: AttributeError at /website/tbt.html
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: also @Nealium, i have done the same method for a different form which is basically a multipart form and does the same thing of generating a pdf. It works for that but not this. i could share the entire code but I don't  know how to do it here